# How to acquire semaphore in order to notify waiting threads on that semaphore? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

There are several consumer threads waiting on a semaphore for data that arrives asynchronously, supplied by a single producer thread. How can the producer acquire the semaphore to notify them if the consumers have already grabbed it? Over here, it is blocked and cannot do a notifyAll()

```
 Object receiveSemaphore = new Object();

// consumer threads
synchronized (receiveSemaphore) {
    while (!dataIsReady) {
        try {
            receiveSemaphore.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

// producer thread          
synchronized (receiveSemaphore) {
    dataIsReady = true;
    receiveSemaphore.notifyAll();
}
```

of course, removing the 'synchronized' causes a

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
```

Again, the producer thread is blocked, and cannot acquire the semaphore to notify the consumers.

**Update:** I should mention that this fails the second time the data is ready. the first time data was ready, the producer did not block. the next time data was produced, the producer blocked. Also there are two places in the code where the producer does a notifyAll() but I am showing it as only one place here.

**Update 2:** Unfortunately, I was not able to reduce the program to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as I did not understand where exactly the problem was - furthermore, these were actually JavaFX Services, not plain threads.

I moved all irrelevant code out of the synchronized block. 
I used jstack to get a thread dump and TDA to view it.
It reported there were 2 monitors (out of other irrelevant ones).
One of them was a StringBuffer that contained the data, and the other was the class itself.
However it did not report any waiting threads.
I had made one method of the class synchronized and now I removed the keyword.
The thread contention seems to have gone.

By the way, receiveSemaphore is simply an Object - a generic semaphore, not the class java.util.Semaphore.

Comment: Make your life easier, use the `Semaphore` class. Actually, use the full `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Why don't you use a `BlockingQueue`? They are designed specifically for this.

Comment: Read the javadoc on the `wait()` method (hint, it answers your question).  Also, don't use the word "semaphore" here because it is something different than what you are doing.

Comment: and no, don't use the Semaphore class (as @SotiriosDelimanolis recommends) as that class is rarely useful.

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, I have read it but I don't see what I am missing in the wait() method

Comment: @JBNizet has repeated the answer from the javadoc in his answer.

Comment: @jtahlborn so why isn't the producer able to acquire the monitor? I am doing a wait()

Comment: @likejiujitsu just use a `BlockingQueue`; it is the standard, bare-bones, proven structure for that. And examples abound when you seach on the net.

Comment: @fge thanks, I shall look at `BlockingQueue` but I still want to know why the producer cannot acquire the semaphore.

Comment: you're saying the producer cannot currently acquire the monitor? (that wasn't clear from your question).

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, I thought I communicated it clearly with "Over here, it is blocked and cannot do a notifyAll()", and also in the code?

Comment: @Gray Yes. `volatile boolean dataIsReady = false;`

Comment: On thing to do is to remove the semaphore and the `dataIsReady` and replace it with a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: If you do a thread-dump of your process, you should be able to see what thread owns the monitor.

Comment: @jtahlborn In Netbeans7.3 debugger, I pause execution and in the Debug window, view the threads. The IDE labels them differently from when I print out in my code `Thread.currentThread().getId()` so it is not obvious to correlate. Anyway it says that Thread-8 "Owned Monitor: java.lang.Object (#4282)" and Thread-6 "Waiting for Monitor: java.lang.Object (#4282)"

Comment: I wonder if 'Owned Monitor' is past tense. There is no 'Owns Monitor'.

Comment: @fge I don't want to change this to a BlockingQueue unless I know what is broken with it.

Comment: @likejiujitsu then reproduce the bug in an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/); but for code you need to get working, use a `BlockingQueue`. All the more that you will have to get used to it more than `Semaphore`.

Comment: @fge, perhaps I should mention that this fails the second time the data is ready. the first time data was ready, the producer did not block. the next time data was produced, the producer blocked.

Comment: @likejiujitsu - you should post your actual code, because the code that you've posted won't show any such behavior. Once the consumer calls `wait()`, the monitor is released; for that matter, once `dataIsReady` becomes `true`, the while-loop will exit and the consumers won't attempt to grab the monitor again. Your actual code is either doing something that blocks (without releasing the monitor) inside a `synchronized` block, or you're not seeing the behavior that you think you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I was not able to reduce the program to a SSCCE as I did not understand where exactly the problem was - furthermore, these were actually JavaFX Services, not plain threads.

I moved all irrelevant code out of the synchronized block. I used jstack to get a thread dump and TDA to view it. It reported there were 2 monitors (out of other irrelevant ones). One of them was a StringBuffer that contained the data, and the other was the class itself. However it did not report any waiting threads. I had made one method of the class synchronized and now I removed the keyword. The thread contention seems to have gone.

By the way, receiveSemaphore is simply an Object - a generic semaphore, not the class java.util.Semaphore.

Comment: `receiveSemaphore` is **not** a semaphore but a monitor. In short, a semaphore has a value and two methods, "up" and "down".